# How fast the human eye can [temporarily] change its color?

Tags: eyes, human-eye

I know that human eye can change its color during lifetime because of disease or medication ([similar question on Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24268/is-it-biologically-possible-for-an-adults-eye-color-to-change)). And I know that it may change depending on the lighting.

But I saw several times as the eyes of man with the bright eyes changed color  (blue/gray/green) without changing environment. Is it possible to temporarily change eye color due to the change of emotional state (as a consequence of the effect of hormones or something else) in just a few of minutes? If so, what are the processes behind this?

Or it just optical/psychological illusion for the observer?

Comment: It is just optical illusion of observer. Eye color cannot change by effect of hormone (somebody correct me if I'm wrong) and not at all in a few minutes.

Comment: In a few minutes? Hardly possible - it will take some time for the pigment cells in the eye to produce and distribute the pigment.

Comment: @another'Homosapien',  thanks for your comment.

Comment: Keep in mind blue eyes contain no blue pigment, it is purely a refractory effect.